# How do I combine two media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

How do I combine two media queries? One is for smaller devices and one for bigger devices, but only in portrait mode!

```
 @media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape){
#div {margin-top: 20px;}
}

}
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 481px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait){
{margin-top: 20px;}
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Not fully clear what you want to combine, but basically you separate them with a comma

**eg**

```
@media only screen and (orientation : landscape) , only screen and (min-device-width : 481px) and (orientation : portrait) { ...
```

Comment: important if you want to shorten whatever you can: **THE SPACES AROUND THE ```and``` ARE NECESSARY**! (whoever thought that was a good idea ;) )

Answer (score 45):

These are the operators for media queries:

- `,` (comma, which works as an OR in a list of media queries)
- `and`
- `not`
- `only`

Examples:

```
@media screen and (color), print and not (color) {...}
@media (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 767px) {...}
@media (max-width: 639px), (min-width: 768px) {...}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

#### Precedence

- `,` is interpreted as the delimiter in a list of single media queries which are ORed. So each media query between the commas is first evaluated, then they are ORed together. This gives the comma / OR the lowest precedence.
- `not` always applies to a whole media query, without extending over a comma. This gives NOT the second lowest precendence after the comma / OR.
- `not` and `only` are mutually exclusive and have the same precedence.
- `and` has the highest precedence
- `()` parentheses are only used around media features and their values, i.e. `(color)` or `(min-width: 320px)`. They may NOT be used to change precedence by grouping expressions.