# combining two media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to test media queries out. I want the background color to render blue when the width is less <= 600 and height <= 400 pixels.

I've tried using:

1. `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (max-height: 400px)`,
2. `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and only screen (max-height: 400px)`,
3. `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px and max-height: 400px)`,
4. `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px), (max-height: 400px)`

but 1-3 didn't do anything and 4 rendered the background blue if either statement were true. Whenever I Google what I want to do I see answers that say solutions like #4. (e.g. [this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897946/how-do-i-combine-two-media-queries)) This is not what I want.

I got it working by using the nested queries below. **Is this the best/only way to do what I want or is there a cleaner solution?**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    @media only screen and (max-height: 400px) {
        body {
            background-color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure #1 doesn't work? It's the direct equivalent of the nested rules that you have.

Comment: @BoltClock That's embarrassing. I don't know how I goofed it up.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would be your first proposed solution<sup>1</sup> which actually just works fine - see snippet below (expand to full size):

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 300px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (max-height: 400px) {

  div {
    background-color: red;
  }


}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

<sup>1</sup> `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (max-height: 400px)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).