# How to combine two media queries?

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

How can I combine the queries below? Please help me understand how it can be done.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px)  {
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 900px) {
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I combine two media queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897946/how-do-i-combine-two-media-queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```css
@media (max-width: 576px), (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 900px) {
    /* Your code */
}
```

However, I recommend you to separate them since the 1st one targets mobiles and the 2nd one targets mainly tablets and small computers.

For more info go to https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Answer (score 2):

In your question u just need to add a comma ',' to combine them

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px), @media (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 900px)  {
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

Suggestion: notice in your example u are trying to apply the max-width two times with same style. Try to add only one max-width. if u just use your second code then also the result will be same.

But coming back to your question, there are some operators used to operate the `@media queries`

These are the operators for media queries

- , (comma, which works as an OR in a list of media queries)
- and
- not
- only

Hope this solves your problem. Enjoy !

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I tried your solution that I think is working. I request you to help me with ensuring all three buttons on the page are linear across all resolution. I find that it is breaking somewhere around 755px. https://packedwithpurpose.gifts/gift-concierge/

Comment: It is strange that it is breaking at 752px because the existing CSS should have already taken care of it.